# Flat CheckBox using CSS

Tags: css, checkbox, stylesheet

I need to flat and style `CheckBox` in my aspx page. I used below **css** code. but nothing happen.

```
input[type="checkbox"]
{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
}
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable cross-browser way to style checkboxes, radio buttons or select fields, so the best results are achieved by creating the illusion of styled elements through the use of images. A simple web search for "styled checkboxes" will provide you with numerous samples.

You may also want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4148544/1715692).